# Type mismatch error in vba while search and update

Tags: excel, vba, find

The code below throws a `Runtime Error: 13 Type mismatch`. I have a list of thousands of URLs in the `Sheet3, column A` where I run my vba script. It finds each of the URLs in `Sites, column B` of 300 workbooks which is in a folder. If found, the `column E` of the same row is updated with `Yes`.

```
Sub ReplaceInFolder()
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim strReplace As String
Dim i As Long
Dim FoundCell As Variant
Dim FoundNo As String

strReplace = "Yes"
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If .Show Then
        strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        MsgBox "No folder selected!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    strPath = strPath & "\"
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
Do While strFile <> ""
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile, AddToMRU:=False)
    For Each wsh In wbk.Worksheets
    If wsh.Name = "Sites" Then
    For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set FoundCell = wsh.Range("B:B").Find(What:=Cells(i, "A").Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
       If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
     FoundNo = FoundCell.Address
       Debug.Print FoundCell.Address
       Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
   wsh.Cells(FoundCell.Row, 5).Value = strReplace
   Set FoundCell = wsh.Cells.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
   If FoundCell.Address = FoundNo Then Exit Do
   Loop
   End If
    Next i
    End If
    Next wsh
    wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
    strFile = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile` ..  `strFile` already contains `strPath` .. because `strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")` .. `FoundCell` is variant used as range.

Comment: I encounter application/ object defined error if I change. Any help with the workaround? Changing FoundCell to Range still throws the mismatch error

Comment: what did you change?

Comment: I think the problem is with the mismatch of datatypes, long and text. Please bear my silliness, I am new to vba.

Comment: Changing FoundCell as Range did not help, encountered same mismatch error. I will check the datatypes of all entries in the sheets.

Comment: Checked it .. my mistake on strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*").. your earlier code is right .. Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile .. Just try changing the FoundCell as range

Comment: Yes.. Mismatch must be datatype error.. Yu can use debug.print at every level to check the output using step-into (F8) debugging. Also for add `wsh.` before each `Range` and `Cells` reference .... Like `For i = 1 To wsh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set FoundCell = wsh.Range("B:B").Find(What:=wsh.Cells(i, "A").Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)` .. If there is still a problem edit the question with new code. So that, someone could help you. I am not very good at vba either. Still learning here on SO.

Comment: Debug is helping. The code is getting stuck at long URLs as below: http://XXXday.com/live/6978/1/%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D8%A8%D8%AB-%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%B1-%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A9-%D9%83%D9%88%D9%84%D9%86-%D9%88-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%B1%D9%86-%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%86%D8%AE-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%85-2020-02-16, http://jb.com/stream1/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=497f046a91a9f43dbfda2041993de9b60f58ce81-1580565231-0-AUX-DyqveQ71w5xQKtTHfBhDSr-aGd8IB_B9PiV2k0ftGBZx5qt_xY34fXxo8Y0nK_BdNW_ZoJXsDneoSPRQ9DnZO-fREJ05N2vkCfWhLkkN-

Comment: The error occurs for values in cells that have more than 255 characters (that's a limit). I'm looking into it. The code seems fine.

Comment: Thank you, I am currently resuming the loop when error encounters.